# Want feedback from someone I've disappointed

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word should I use in the following situation?

I have done some work for somebody, but he is not satisfied. I still want the feedback from him, and am trying to convince him to give me some feedback (likely bad); I honestly wouldn't *like* to get negative feedback, but I would prefer to receive some form of response rather than nothing. Is this a good way to ask?

> Please, at least give me feedback (**maybe** bad).

What should I use in place of **maybe** to make it a good sentence?

Comment: If you wanted to keep it in the brief for that you have used, you could try: "I would appreciate comments or criticisms."

Comment: Actually, I was trying to get the meaning of a word in English which we speak in our own language(Hindi), but because I cannot ask in Hindi, I was trying to make it clear by framing a situation. But, now I feel that I am not completely successful in conveying my intended word's meaning here.

Comment: The standard phrasing for businesses is [We welcome criticism, good or bad](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LvYDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22we+welcome+criticism%22&hl=en&ei=54CgTtGqOIii8QORmbzGBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22we%20welcome%20criticism%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know this person is not satisfied, I would suggest rewriting the whole sentence rather than the one word. Perhaps something along the lines of

> I understand that you are not currently satisfied with my work, and I would like to hear from you regarding how I can bring my work up to your expected standards.

This will (hopefully) encourage a more positive attitude from your client, even if the feedback is negative, and can (hopefully) open an opportunity for you to improve their satisfaction with your work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines, assuming of course that you are willing to correct whatever problems the client has with your work:

> I strive to ensure that every client is satisfied. It has come to my attention that you are unsatisfied with the service(s) I provided, and I would like to make things right. Please let me know what you are unsatisfied with and I will do everything within my power to correct the situation. Thank you.

If you aren't interested/able to remedy the situation, then perhaps this would work:

> I am sorry to learn that you find my work to be unsatisfactory. If you would be so kind, please inform me what aspect(s) of my services you found to be lacking. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

> Please, at least give me feedback (even if it’s bad).

Comment: Feedback is not a count noun.

Comment: Or perhaps "Please give me feedback (*even if* bad)".

Comment: ... (even if it is negative).